# error passing hex code to php script with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a colour vlue selected from a colour picker to a style sheet using jquery ajax and php. I can't figure out how to do this though.

my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#colorpicker").on("change",function(){     
var backgroundColour = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({url: 'styles.php', type: 'post', data: 
{backgroundColour: backgroundColour}, dataType: "text"});
               console.log(backgroundColour);

               });
});
```

my php

```
<?php

//setup the content-type header and charset.
header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");

$backgroundColour = $_POST['backgroundColour'];
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I have tried changing the ajax call to this

```
 $.ajax({url: 'styles.php', type: 'post', data: 
 backgroundColour, dataType: "text"});
```

I have tried omitting the dataType, but I can't get a value to appear in the php script.

Comment: And what `var_dump` is saying? Also `$(this).val()` points to `document` and `document` does not have value as it's not input element

Comment: @Justinas I have edited the original post to include the line of code i forgot to put in. var_dump is saying array(0) {
}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the color of the element by using this jQuery code:

`var backgroundColor = $("#idofcolorpicker").val();`

Or if the colorpickers has a class:

`var backgroundColor = $(".classofcolorpicker").val();`

Comment: Getting the colour isnt my issue its sending the colour to my styles.php file